# Passing indexPath from UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, nsindexpath

In my application I have one`UITableViewController` (Uctovatrida0TableViewController) and two other`UIViewContoller` (DetailViewController and examples).

Now I have a problem because I do not know how to identify index (from `indexPath.row`) in my first`UIViewController` to then correctly referred to another `UIViewController`.

**The code in my Uctovatrida0TableViewController.m (works well):**

```
-(void) showDetailsForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    DetailViewController* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController"];
    Ucty* ucet;

    if(isFiltered)
    {
        ucet = [_filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        ucet = [self.alldataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    vc.uctyItem = ucet;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
}
```

**Code in my class DetailViewConroller where I need indexPath from Uctovatrida0TableViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Priklad"])
    {
        Priklad *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        Ucty* ucet;

        //of course this does not work
        ucet = [self.alldataArray objectAtIndex:NSIndexPath.row];

        vc.uctyItem = ucet;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
    }
}
```

**Code in my class Priklad.m:**

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (self.uctyItem != newDetailItem)
    {
        self.uctyItem  = newDetailItem;
        [self configureView];

    }
}
- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.uctyItem ) {
        self.prikladLabel.text = self.uctyItem.priklad;
        self.uctykprikladu.text = self.uctyItem.uctykprikladu;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it seems `DetailViewConroller` has a property `uctyItem`. So in your `DetaiViewController`'s `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, you can just call `vc.uctyItem = self.uctyItem;`.

Comment: Thank you, but why is output in the class Priklad a null?

Comment: If you do as I suggested above, you're calling `setUctyItem:` not `setDetailItem:`, so `configureView` is not being called.

Comment: Of course, my mistake. I tried to use it this way, but the result is still (null):- (void)setUctyItem:(Ucty *)uctyItem{if (self.uctyItem != uctyItem){self.uctyItem  = uctyItem;
        [self configureView];}}

Comment: It should be _uctyItem = uctyItem; to avoid an infinite loop on the setter.

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to `DetailViewConroller` that you can set before pushing to it.

`@property (assign, nonatomic) int index;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get selected cell `indexPath` then there is a method for that is : `selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];`